# How to prevent application from crash if unhandled exception happened in some child thread

Tags: java, android, exception

If I do a regular Java application then all exceptions which uncaught, get propagated in main thread and I can catch them here. However I do not see how I can use that in Android application. Let's say I have some third party library which uses some JDK 1.6 API and access to these API generates unhandled exception which crashes my application. Since I do not have direct control of thread creations in third party libraries, I can't use Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler. So what's way to catch such exception and notify a user without crashing application?

Answer (score 3):

Just set a [default exception handler for all threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29)

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to work. It is possible for the `ThreadGroup` containing the third party thread to catch the error and call `System.exit()` (or whatever the Android equivalent is).

Comment: True. But that's just very bad library design.